# How to call Spark Functions in Sparklyr with invoke

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, flatmap, sparklyr

I am trying to use invoke in RStudio's Sparklyr to do a simple word count off of a text file in HDFS and have not figured out the syntax.  I can get the whole file back as a list by using (similar to the count example in the SparklyR doc on extensions - http://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html):

```
getFileCollect <- function(sc, path) {
    spark_context(sc) %>% 
      invoke("textFile", path, 1L) %>%
        invoke("collect")
}

fc <- getFileCollect(sc, "hdfs:///tmp/largeTomes/bigEx.txt")
```

What I want to do is a flatmap on that text file to do the classic scala code:

```
.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
            .map(word => (word, 1))
            .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

But haven't even come close on figuring out the syntax of invoke.  flatMap is a method of textFile.  Surely somebody has done this before and I'm just not thinking right.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you figured it out (it has been a few months), but for using collect with dplyr, you just have to put it that way:

```
myFileCollected <- myFileDF %>% collect
```

Then i would try to use dplyr functions, ie mutate (thats one of sparklyr advantages).